# Collapsing A Collection View Cell

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a scroll view, inside a collection view cell. The scroll view has a class of its own (ClassA), as does the collection view (ClassB). When you tap the index row, it expands. Sweet, works just fine. Only problem is, you have to tap on the index row to collapse the cell. Since there is a UIScrollView hanging out in the cell, tapping on it won't collapse the cell. So, what I did was create tap detection in the scroll view. The tap detections selector then handles collapsing the cell via notifications:

Class A:

```
- (void)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    // Post a notification to collapse
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"collapseCell" object:nil];
}
```

Class B:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(deselectItemAtIndexPath:animated:)
                                          name:@"collapseCell" object:nil];
}
```

Error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CollectionViewController deselectItemAtIndexPath:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7caa

Answer (score 0):

That `NSNotification`is not doing what you think it's doing. Its not calling or trying to call the `UICollectionView`'s delegate method, `deselectItemAtIndexPath:animated:`. Its actually looking for a different method, but with the same signature as the `UICollectionView`s delegate method.

Make a test method, call it something simple and see if that works to confirm what I think is happening.

Comment: Interesting... Making a test method now.

Comment: Yes it called upon my test method just fine. How would I go about having it call my collection view's delegate method?

Comment: In your test method, call the collection views delegate method?

Comment: How would I do that, like "`[collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:currentlySelectedIndexPath animated:YES];`"? Apparently the collection view doesn't even have an outlet (working with sloppy code).

Comment: If the class is a subclass of UICollectionView... [self collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:currentlySelectedIndexPath]; if not.. then [self.collectionView collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:currentlySelectedIndexPath]